# Ребят помогите с кнопкой на python

Tags: python

Хотел сделать  сделать кнопку открытие вк, все сделал

```
tk= Tk()
import webbrowser
.......
.......
.......

bl = Button(tk,image = vk,command=webbrowser.open("https://vk.com/feed", new=2, autoraise="True"))                          
bl.place(x=610,y=798, width=200, height=100)
```

tk.mainloop

При запуске сразу открывается сайт и кнопка не открывать сайт, ошибок нет

Comment: Tk.mainloop забыл в код поставить , кнопка сайт не открывает

Comment: С отступами накосячил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит потому что вы вызываете функцию вместо того, чтобы передать её. Это можно исправить так:

```
bl = Button(tk, image=vk, command=lambda: webbrowser.open("https://vk.com/feed", new=2, autoraise="True"))
```